# How to connect server to Binance Smart Chain using the Web3.js library?

Tags: ethereum, web3js, binance, binance-chain

I'm trying to connect my small server web app in ExpressJS to the BSC blockchain, but without success.

As per my understanding, the Web3 library provides all the required stuff under the hood, and I can connect by calling

`new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(urlToRpcNode))`

By following this, I put the following into my function, which serves as a Web3 object init:

`return new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org));`

According to BscScan, the given argument is the URL to the RPC Node for BSC https://bscscan.com/apis#rpc.

Unfortunately, awaiting this call just gets stuck forever and doesn't return anything.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

I found another link to Binance Docs, where it outlines the specific process for connecting to BSC. Here is how they do it:

`const web3 = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443');`

https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/create-wallet.html#connect-to-bsc-network

Unfortunately, this gives me the same result.

Comment: I suggest you contact Binance Smart Chain support if the method above does not work, as it looks correct.

Comment: Oh I think I've found the issue, but not the solution. The BSC docs say this is the way for client-side apps. I'm attempting to connect from my express.js server. Would the process be different in this case since I don't have a default provider such as Metamask on my server?

Comment: Web3.js has no practical difference between client side apps and server side apps.

Comment: And what about the lack of Metamask or a similar provider? I've been digging around the web and seems like I need to either 1. Run my own node on the server or 2. Connect to an external RPC node provider such as ANKR

Comment: The second is correct. How to get RPC node for Binance Smart Chain, please contact Binance Smart Chain development support team. StackOverflow is not an place to support a third party product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few months later, I remembered asking this. I ended up using an external RPC node provider (fe. QuickNode, Ankr, Infura).

I don't have my exact code on hand, but I know that the steps were as follows:

- Open an account on a platform which offers RPC services
- Eg. Infura, Ankr, QuickNode (these were the ones that I found)
- These services will let you create your own node for a certain blockchain (I saw Eth, Bsc, Polygon, AvalancheC and many others)
- After you create your own node, which is of course, paid service, you get an HTTP link for your node, which looks something like this `https://mynode2241235.ankr.com/`, let's call that `LINK` from now.
- Back on my server, I took the regular `Web3` connection code snippet and just modified it by putting this `LINK` as an `HttpProvider`, so sth like this:

`const instance = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(LINK));`

Answer (score 6):

The above web3 part works fine. Please try the below lines,

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
const web3_bsc = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443');
```

Then using the `web3_bsc`, access the functions in your contract or perform any functions that **web3** supports.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the issue? Also check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.